# Lower bound related to derivative of $j$-invariant

Tags: real-analysis, analytic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, fourier-analysis, modular-forms

Recall the $j$-invariant function, namely,
$$
j(\tau)=\frac{1}{q}+\sum_{k\geq 0}c_kq^k,
$$
where $q=e^{2\pi i \tau}$ and the coefficients $(c_k)_k$ are in the OEIS sequence A000521.

By using some normalisation and derivative (I'll omit the details), it is possible to prove that
$$
e^{2\pi}=\sum_{k\geq 1}kc_ke^{-2k\pi}.
$$
Thus, I would like to study the following problem:

**Problem.** *Let $\epsilon>0$ be a real number, $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\ldots\in (1,1+\epsilon)$ and set $\delta:=\min_{i}\{\alpha_i\}$. How to obtain an effective lower bound for
$$
\left|e^{2\alpha_0\pi}-\sum_{k\geq 1}kc_ke^{-2k\alpha_i\pi}\right|
$$
in terms of $\delta-1$?*

I believe something like $(\delta-1)^{2+o(1)}$ should work, but I have no success by using any approach.

Could you guys please help me with that?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how that would work - you can let all $\alpha_i\to 1$ while keeping them in $(1,1+\epsilon)$, and the difference tends to $0$.

Comment: You are right. I made some confusion. I just edited, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{j'(i+z)}{z}$ is analytic and non-zero on $|z|<1/100$, it attains its minimum and maximum modulus on $|z|=1/100$.

[Therefore](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+abs%281728*KleinInvariantJ%27%28i%2B0.01*exp%28i*t%29%29%2F0.01%29+from+t%3D+0+to+2*pi) $$\left|\frac{j'(i+z)}{z}\right| \in (48000,50000)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please provide me some reference? Also, it is possible to use the same idea do obtain a lower bound for $e^{2\pi t}-e^{2\pi}+\sum_{k\geq 1}c_k(e^{-2k\pi t}-e^{-2k\pi})$ in function of $(t-1)$?

Comment: A reference for what?

Comment: For $j'(i+z)/z$ not zero on that open disc. But I think it is ok.

Comment: $j(a)=j(b)$ iff $b\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})a$ gives that $j'(\tau)=0$ iff $\tau\in SL_2(\Bbb{Z})i \cup SL_2(\Bbb{Z})e^{2i\pi/3}$ and $j''(i)\ne 0$. So it remains to check that $|\tau-i|<1/100$ doesn't contain any of those, pretty obvious from [this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-invariant#The_fundamental_region) of the $SL_2(\Bbb{Z})$-orbit of the standard fundamental domain in the upper half-plane

Comment: Thanks! But how the minimum and maximum of $|j'(i+z)/z|$ can be applied to my problem? Sorry, I didn't realize it.

Comment: This is what you asked a lower bound for $j'(i+z)$ for $|z|$ small

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132547/discussion-between-jean-and-reuns).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. However, I still didn't realize about the full relation between $j'(i+z)/z$ and the difference $\left|e^{2\alpha_0\pi}-\sum_{k\geq 1}kc_ke^{-2k\alpha_i\pi}\right|$. Could you please give me some more details? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think in my case would be $j'(i(1+z))/z$. Am I missing something? Also, I can not suppose that $|z|<1/100$. I only have $|z|<1$.

Comment: No you don't, $j'(1/(d+i))=0$ for all $d\in \Bbb{Z}$, that makes infinitely many zeros of $j'(i+z)$ on $|z|<1$.

Comment: Why $j'(i+z)$ instead of $j'(i(1+z))$? The last one seems more natural. Thanks!